# How do I share a link in Google Reader that I do not subscribe to?

Tags: google-reader, delicious

I really enjoy using [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com).  I subscribe to the sites I frequently visit/read and often share/like/star those links.  But I have yet to see how I can share a link on a site I don't normally read/subscribe to.

This is something that [Delicious](http://delicious.com/) does very well, and I use a [bookmarklet](http://delicious.com/help/bookmarklets) within Chrome to achieve this.

**How do I share a link in Google Reader that I do not subscribe to?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Google Reader Bookmarklet](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2008/05/share-anything-anytime-anywhere.html)

It allows you to click a link on your bookmarks toolbar and it automatically shares the page you're currently on through Google Reader, exactly what you want I think.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.  :)